# How do I stop dark mode from flickering when page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I'm having a difficulty in stopping my night mode from flickering whenever a user reload page or try navigating to their timeline, the dark mode flicker  making it not look professional even though I check some solution on here that said I should put the dark mode function at the top of my base HTML for it  to be the first to load, which didn't work in my case and I was wondering what seem to be the problem or  what could I do, can anyone be of help.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"⚡>

<head>
   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link href="{% static 'images/logot.png' %}" rel="icon" type="image/png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@trevoreyre/autocomplete-js/dist/style.css"/>

    
    <!--AMP-->
   
  
    <!-- Basic Page Needs
        ================================================== -->
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
     

    <!-- icons
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/icons.css' %}">
    

    <!-- CSS 
    ================================================== -->
  
   

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/uikit.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/tailwind.css' %}">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css' %}">
    

  
</head>

<body>
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  <div class="container" id="id_loading_spinner" style="display: none">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row mx-auto flex-grow-1 justify-content-center">
      <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div id="wrapper" class="is-collapse">
        {% include 'snippets/base_css.html' %}
        {% include 'snippets/base_js.html' %}
        {% include 'snippets/header.html' %}
        {% include 'snippets/sidebar.html' %}
         {% block content %} 
         
         {% endblock %}
    </div>
   
    {% else %}
    <div class="lg:p-12 max-w-xl lg:my-0 my-12 mx-auto p-6 space-y-">
        <a href="{% url 'account:login' %}">Please login from here<h1 class="lg:text-2xl text-xl font-semibold mb-6"> Login </h1></a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}


    <!-- Javascript
    ================================================== -->
<script>
function displayLoadingSpinner(isDisplayed){
  var spinner = document.getElementById("id_loading_spinner")
  if(isDisplayed){
    spinner.style.display = "block"
  }
  else{
    spinner.style.display = "none"
  }
}
</script>

<!-- For Dark mode -->
 <script >
var darkMode = false;

// default to system setting
if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
    darkMode = true;
}
// preference from localStorage should overwrite
if (localStorage.getItem("gmtNightMode") === 'dark') {
    darkMode = true;
} else if (localStorage.getItem("gmtNightMode") === 'light') {
    darkMode = false;
}

if (darkMode) {
    document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark');
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementById("night-mode").addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark');
    localStorage.setItem("gmtNightMode", document.documentElement.classList.contains('dark')? 'dark' : 'light');
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: In the code you posted the code that toggles the `dark` class is not on top. Try moving it right after the `<body>` tag. This should block the entire page from rendering until that code is executed

Comment: Okay I had applied your solution, by moving the dark mode right after the <body> tag,  but then when I reload the page or try navigating to timeline  it just turns the dark mode right back off, instead I would want it to stay On when navigating or when 
 the page is reloaded.